# Would it be ungrammatical to use "ouverte" as a brand name?

Tags: grammaire, sens, choix-de-mot, temps-grammatical

We are exploring starting a business for lingerie business targeting women. Since 'ouverts' are type of lingerie, we wanted to explore using the feminine form 'ouverte' as a reference to ouverts as well as centering the brand around the theme of an open minded woman (femme ouverte d'espirit). Hence, we are more keen on 'ouverte' than 'ouvert'. However, we are concerned that using 'ouverte' may seem ungrammatical, in the wrong tense or convey unintended connotations to native French speakers.

Would any native French speakers be able to advise us? Merci beaucoup!

Comment: Would your intended audience be international, English-speaking, or French-speaking ? If you intend to address a French audience, note that *ouvert* as a name for a piece of underwear will not be understood in French.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brand names aren't restricted by grammar so that point wouldn't be an issue anyway. On the other hand, I'm afraid *ouverte* specifically applying to women's underwear risk to convey the unintended connotations (open underwear?) you suspect in your question.

Comment: Many thanks for replying! 

Perhaps I wasn't but we DO want to refer to ouverts as that will be the main line we are intending to import.

Comment: TBH, I'm far to be a specialist in women underwear... *Ouverte* might not be such a bad idea after all. In any case, it isn't rude and it is positive. *Fermée* for example would be a very poor choice :-)